# Input validation generating data-* attributes ONLY on Primary key and checkbox type input tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

I've created a sample `ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1` web app created using `VS2015-Update3`. It generates input tags with **data -* attributes** only on a model property that is a Primary Key, and on a property that is of type `bool`. For instance, in the following example the generated html (shown below) is showing the data-attributes only on the input tag generated for properties `MyEntityId` and `Prop2` of the model. **NOTE**: I'm using the default ASP.NET Core Web Application template that automatically installs Jquery, Bootstrap, etc.

**Model**:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int MyEntityId { get; set; }

    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "char(2)")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{2,2}$", ErrorMessage = "Must enter two digit numbers"), StringLength(2)]
    public string TestCode { get; set; }

    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    public bool Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
<form asp-controller="TestController" asp-action="TestAction" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div><input type="hidden" asp-for="MyEntityId" /></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Prop1" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Prop1" class="form-control" style="margin-top:15px;" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Prop1" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="TestCode" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input asp-for="TestCode" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="TestCode" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="StartDate" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="StartDate" type="date" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="StartDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Prop2" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <input asp-for="Prop2" class="form-control" style="zoom:0.5;margin-top:25px;" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Prop2" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="testVal">Save</button>
</form>
```

**Generated Html**:

```
<div><input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The MyEntityId field is required." id="MyEntityId" name="MyEntityId" value="54321"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="StateName">Prop1</label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="form-control" readonly="" type="text" id="Prop1" name="Prop1" value="TestVal">
        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Prop1" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="TestCode">TestCode</label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="TestCode" name="TestCode" value="">
        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="TestCode" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="StartDate">Start Date</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" value="2015-10-01">
        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="StartDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Prop2">Test Prop2</label>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Test Prop2 is required." id="Prop2" name="Prop2" style="zoom:0.5;margin-top:25px;" type="checkbox" value="true">
        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Prop2" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cannot duplicate this  at all and it is not the normal behavior. I can only assume you must have overridden the default behavior somewhere. I suggest for a start, you comment out `<input asp-for="StartDate" type="date" class="form-control" />` and replace with `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate)` and post the html rendered for that (it will help to narrow down the issue)

Comment: And note that even nullable properties will generate `data-val-*` attributes, for example for `StartDate` you will get `data-val-date="The field StartDate must be a date.`

Comment: @StephenMuecke You're correct in that I may be overriding the default behavior somewhere since when I created a test app with only the above example. It did indeed show `data-*` attribute for `TestCode`. However, for the `StateDate` it did not show data-* attribute: for tag helper it shows `<input type="date" class="form-control" id="StartDate" name="StartDate" value="">` whereas for html helper it shows `<input id="StartDate" name="StartDate" type="text" value="">`. The reason probably could be that I'm using `DateTime` as optional `DateTime?`

Comment: That makes no difference - the `TextBoxFor()` method will add `data-val-date="..."` because the value has to be a either `null` or a valid date (if a user entered "xyx", it would generate a validatio error say it must be a date. If its not adding that attribute for you then you have some code somewhere that is overriding the normal behavior (e.g. a custom extension method or `EditorTemplate`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hmm. It probably then may have something to do with my `VS2015` settings since I created a new MVC core app with just only the above example along with `Individual User Authentication` option. Nothing else is there except their built-in code and my above example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your issue is that `TestCode` does not have validation on it, despite having both `RegularExpression` and `StringLength` attributes applied. `MyEntityId` and `Prop2` are non-nullable, so there's an implicit required validation for those, while `Prop1` and `StartDate` *are* nullable and do not have any explicit validation applied. As a result, those are rightly not validated.

`TestCode` is weird, though. I'm not sure you'd actually get `data-*` attributes, as both the regular expression and string length can be satisfied using the HTML attributes `pattern` and `maxlength`, respectively. *But*, you should then have `pattern` and `maxlength` applied to the input for `TestCode` which is not the case.

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms#the-input-tag-helper), the code you have should work, and at the least, it seems that `StringLength` is applied via `data-val-maxlength` rather than (or perhaps in addition to) using the `maxlength` attribute. There's either some bug at play, or there's something else in your codebase that is preventing the correct behavior from occurring. However, without more code, it's impossible to say.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying why there are implicit required validations on two of the properties and why the other two nullable ones do not have data-* attributes. Your assumption is correct. `TestCode` is more of an issue. Just so you know `TesCode` actually allows me to enter, say, `abc` on client side. It only complains on the server side when SQL server (as expected) complains that char(2) can't have three characters in it. This makes me to believe that it has something to do with data-* attribute not getting generated on `TestCode`

Comment: No, even if there was something wrong with the client-side validation, the modelbinder should still catch it server-side. As long as you're properly checking `ModelState.IsValid` you should never get to the point of saving to the DB, let alone get a DB integrity exception. Confirm that you're using the right class, that the class actually has this validation on the property, and that your code is compiled fully. It's possible a build failed and you're still running a previous version that didn't include this validation, for example.